# How to listing files PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know how to upload files, listing, and download files in PHP?

I want the users upload / list / download files, For example: file "Assignment Guide.doc".

Below are the code that I've done for upload, listing, download.
The code below successfully let the users upload, list , and download files. But the file name that shown in the database, list page, and directory in the explorer is "AssignmentGuideline.doc" instead of "Assignment Guide.doc". I wonder if there is any code that makes the files name shown in the database, list page, and directory in the explorer is "Assignment Guideline.doc".....

**upload-file-process.php**

```
<?php
    require("connection.php");
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['UserName'];

    //This is the directory where files will be saved
    $filename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $filesize = intval($_FILES['file']['size']);
    $filenospace = str_replace(' ','',$filename); 
    $udir= "users/".$username."/";
    $ufile = $udir .$filenospace;

    //This gets all the other information from the form 
    $file = ($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $filenospace1 = str_replace(' ','',$file); 

    //Writes the information to the database 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files(UserName,FileName,Path,Size,Date) VALUES('$username', '$filenospace1', '$udir','$filesize',NOW())") ; 

    //Writes the file to the server 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $ufile)){
        //Tells you if its all ok
        header('location:upload.php?feedback3=uploadsuccessful');
    }
    else {
        //Gives and error if its not
        header('location:upload.php?feedback3=uploaderror');
    }
?>
```

---

**userpage.php** - Where shows the uploaded files and its download links

```
<div class="box6">
    <h3>File Lists</h3>
    <?php
        echo '<table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td width="50px"><b>Name</b></td>
                <td width="60px"><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Date</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>
                <td><b>Sharing</b></td>
            </tr>';

        include_once("connection.php");
        $sqlUpload = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE UserName = '$username'");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlUpload)){
            $filename = $row['FileName'];
            $path = $row['Path'];
            $size = $row['Size'];
            $date = $row['Date'];
            $string_space = str_replace('','&nbsp;',$filename);

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td><b>'.$row['FileName'].'</b></td>
                <td><b>'.$row['Size'].'</b></td>
                <td><b>'.$row['Date'].'</b></td>
                 <td><b><a href='.$row['Path'].''.$string_space.'>Download</a></b></td>
                 <td><b> <form action="userpage.php" method="post">
            <input name="user_name" placeholder="username"> <input type="submit" value="Share" /> </form> </b><td>
            </tr>';
        }
    ?>

    <table width="650">
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
        include_once("connection.php");
        if(isset($_POST['user_name'])){
            $username_friend = $_POST['user_name'];
            $pathnew = 'users/'.$username_friend.'/';
            copy(''.$path.''.$filename.'', 'users/'.$username_friend.'/'.$filename.'');
            $sqlshare= "INSERT INTO files(UserName,FileName,Path,Size,Date) VALUES('$username_friend', '$filename', '$pathnew','$size',NOW())";
            if(mysql_query($sqlshare)){
                echo "success sharing";
            }
            else {
                echo "Failed Sharing";
            }
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are inserting $filenospace1 but regarding this line you replace the space by no  space :

```
$filenospace1 = str_replace(' ','',$file);
```

Don't do this "str_replace" or just insert $file instead of $filenospace1 in your SQL statement :

```
INSERT INTO files(UserName,FileName,Path,Size,Date) VALUES('$username', '$file', '$udir','$filesize',NOW())
```

And finally, to display the data :

```
//Replace this line
$string_space = str_replace('','&nbsp;',$filename);
//by this one
$string_space = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$filename);
```

Comment: So, I just use the second code line? no need to add the first line?

Comment: how about this line: $filenospace = str_replace(' ','',$filename); -- leave it?

Comment: Btw, I've already try your suggestion, and it works. But, when I look into the file explorer, the file is still as no space filename, and also when I click download links, its not working......any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "file explorer" ?

Comment: I think it's too late and your file "Assignment Guide.doc" is already stored with no space in youd DB. Check this and update the record to add the space if necessary

Comment: I mean, windows explorer, where the files is stored....in the database table and webpage, the name that shown is "Assignment Guideline.doc", but in the windows explorer shown as "AssignmentGudeline.doc". Some more, It goes error when clicked download links in the webpage.